# Git in Mapped network drive vs on server

Tags: git

I have a PHP application hosted on an Ubuntu server. I also have the application folder mapped to a network drive on my windows machine.  This folder is a working GIT directory. So, basically, the mapped network drive and the folder on Ubuntu point to the same Git repo.
But when I do a git status, the results I get are different why ?

Comment: What kind of differences? Accessing the same local repository from two different OSes will at least cause different behaviours when it comes to upper/lowercase names and file permissions.

Comment: In windows, it shows a number of files as modified which are not actually but in Ubuntu only the really modified files are shown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some subtle differences in which different OSes handle files, especially text files. Most famously, line endings are different on Linux and on Windows: Windows uses `CRLF` and Linux uses `LF`. While two files may look the same even if they have different line endings, they are still technically different. Some IDEs like IntelliJ show a note in such cases in the commit dialog: "Differences only in line endings".

Usually, Git handles such differences upon commit and check-out, but not when doing a `git status`. Here's what I'm guessing happened in your particular case:

1. You cloned the repo on your Ubuntu machine and checked it out. While doing this, Git checked all files out with `LF` as the line ending, since you're on Ubuntu.
2. You shared the repo through a file share to a Windows machine.
3. When looking at the repo from the Windows machine with `git status`, Git expects everything to use `CRLF` but it finds `LF` instead, thus assuming that the files were modified.